# What is the most elegant way to check if all values in a boolean array are true?

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

I have a boolean array in java:

```
boolean[] myArray = new boolean[10];
```

What's the most elegant way to check if all the values are true?

Comment: if you **really** need a fast way to do that then you'd be better storing your flags in an *int* or a *long* (or even a *long[]*) and do the "math" yourself.  Then you can check up to 32 or 64 values at once.  However I doubt that that particular spot of yours would prove to be a bottleneck.

Comment: @donturner Do you mean fastest as in fast to compute, or fast as in fast to write (less code)?

Comment: Many thanks for the quick responses. I meant fastest as in 'fastest to write', not to execute. Perhaps I should have said 'most elegant'.

Comment: Loop and break when one doesnt. For speed, it would be better to use ints or hashmaps.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

```
public static boolean areAllTrue(boolean[] array)
{
    for(boolean b : array) if(!b) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: this might be personal preference, but I'd use `isAllTrue(boolean... array)` in case another input is wanted or required for that method in the future. It still accepts arrays, but we don't want to restrict possible future users.

Comment: Tbh I think this is one of the few reasonable answer here. Other answers use other JVM languages, dependencies, `Boolean` (boxed), or are just unnecessarily complicated. Any answer preaching speed didn't include any micro-benchmarks to at least give an idea on how it performed on their machines. Imo, [keep it simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and just go with the vanilla approach.

Answer (score 95):

```
Arrays.asList(myArray).contains(false)
```

Comment: one liner, clear, concise, O(n) lookup, what's not to like here?

Comment: That does only work if it is a Boolean[], not a boolean[]. Because you can't have a List with a primitive, you will end up with Arrays.asList(boolean[]) with a List<boolean[]> which never contains false as it always contains arrays.

Comment: @DavidGeorgReichelt I don't think that's the main concern of the asker. it clearly states. from array of booleans. so...

Comment: @acorello ah I understand now, thanks for the explanation. I removed my original comment :)

Comment: @acorell what comment? XDD

Answer (score 40):

In Java 8, you could do:

```
boolean isAllTrue = Arrays.asList(myArray).stream().allMatch(val -> val == true);
```

Or even shorter:

```
boolean isAllTrue = Arrays.stream(myArray).allMatch(Boolean::valueOf);
```

**Note:**
You need `Boolean[]` for this solution to work. Because you can't have a primitives List.

Comment: `Arrays.asList(myArray).stream().allMatch(Boolean::booleanValue)` will work for both all `true` and all `false`.

Comment: `Arrays.asList(myArray).stream().allMatch(val -> Boolean.TRUE.equals(val));`
this will also handle properly the case if there are null values in the array.

Comment: To check if explicitly true, Arrays.asList(myArray).stream().allMatch(Boolean.TRUE::equals)

Answer (score 18):

It depends how many times you're going to want to find this information, if more than once:

```
Set<Boolean> flags = new HashSet<Boolean>(myArray);
flags.contains(false);
```

Otherwise a short circuited loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  if (!myArray[i]) return false;
}
return true;
```

Comment: `bool` is not Java?! and accessing length each interaction - foreach is (minimally) faster. But the Set idea is cool - +1 for that

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger A good spot, have been C#ing recently and got my bools and booleans mixed up!

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Wait for each should be faster than a simple loop? If the JIT can inline everything and optimize accordingly the iterator solution may be AS fast as the direct access, but certainly not faster (CSE on the array length on the other hand will happen almost certainly). Theoretically starting with `length() - 1` and stopping at 0 may be marginally faster on x86 but that's not even a microoptimization anymore.

Comment: @Voo - the JIT **can** inline everything, must not... foreach is almost the same as above but calls length only once (stored in a local variable) so it is **minimally** faster, as I wrote, and the question was asking for fastest way before being edited yesterday

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Forgot that we were talking about arrays and that Java doesn't use iterators for those, mea culpa.

Comment: -1 because the top example doesn't compile:
`unexpected type
  required: reference
  found:    boolean`

Comment: You can't use primitive as Generic types. By the way how do you say it is more elegant? Creating a collection over an array and then iterating it?

Comment: I would never use your solution, but if I should I would use Arrays.asList*() to create an ArrayList not a HashSet. Because ArrayList just uses array copying which is faster....

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh The original question was 'the fastest way to...', not 'the most elegant way to...'. Yes, creation would be slower, however lookups in a HashSet are `O(1)` whereas in an ArrayList they are `O(n)`, hence my statement about how many times the OP wished to find out this information. Since java lacks reified generics it may also be worth mentioning the cost of boxing the boolean in the contains method, however on any recent JVM this would form a gen 0 collectible and the cost should be neglible. It could also be mitigated by passing `Boolean.False` instead.

Answer (score 13):

I can't believe there's no [`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) solution.

A `BitSet` is an abstraction over a set of bits so we don't have to use `boolean[]` for more advanced interactions anymore, because it already contains most of the needed methods. It's also pretty fast in batch operations since it internally uses `long` values to store the bits and doesn't therefore check every bit separately like we do with `boolean[]`.

```
BitSet myBitSet = new BitSet(10);
// fills the bitset with ten true values
myBitSet.set(0, 10);
```

For your particular case, I'd use [`cardinality()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#cardinality%28%29):

```
if (myBitSet.cardinality() == myBitSet.size()) {
    // do something, there are no false bits in the bitset
}
```

---

Another alternative is using [Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Booleans.html#contains-boolean:A-boolean-):

```
return Booleans.contains(myArray, true);
```

Comment: I think using BitSet is a great idea. However care is needed on comparing cardinality (which counts the bits set to true) and length (which counts all positions, both true and false, up to the last one set to true). I ran into comparing a length of a BitSet correlated to a ListArray that had trailing falses - that is, I needed the ListArray length not the BitSet length.

Comment: That's why you should use .size() and not .length()

Comment: I can't believe there's no _Apache Commons_ solution. Oh, wait, now [there is one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53226864/1744774). ;)

Comment: @MarkRenouf look again in Doc and do some test, KTys is right. e.g. on my java settings .size() return 64 regardless n (... BitSet(n)). 
    !!! Bad sugestion:
When the context is okay someone can use .length() making sure that last value is true and will never be changed.

Answer (score 11):

That line should be sufficient:

[`BooleanUtils.and(boolean... array)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/BooleanUtils.html#and(boolean...))

but to calm the link-only purists:

> Performs an and on a set of booleans.

Comment: Just for clarity for anyone that might be confused if they can't access `BooleanUtils`, it's a part of [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/), so you'll have to add it as a dependency first. Also here's a link to the [implementation](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/BooleanUtils.java#L92=) for anyone curious)

Answer (score 9):

In Java 8+, you can create an `IntStream` in the range of `0` to `myArray.length` and check that all values are `true` in the corresponding (primitive) array with something like,

```
return IntStream.range(0, myArray.length).allMatch(i -> myArray[i]);
```

Comment: This is one of the only right answers here (next to the accepted answer of course). Most of the other highly upvoted answers need ``Boolean[]`` arrays to work, but the question clearly specified a primitive ``boolean[]`` array.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not faster, and definitely not very readable. So, for the sake of colorful solutions...

```
int i = array.length()-1;
for(; i > -1 && array[i]; i--);
return i==-1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
boolean alltrue = true;
for(int i = 0; alltrue && i<booleanArray.length(); i++)
   alltrue &= booleanArray[i];
```

I think this looks ok and behaves well...

Answer (score 0):

You can check all value items are true or false by compare your array with the other boolean array via `Arrays.equal` method like below example :

```
private boolean isCheckedAnswer(List<Answer> array) {
    boolean[] isSelectedChecks = new boolean[array.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        isSelectedChecks[i] = array.get(i).isChecked();
    }

    boolean[] isAllFalse = new boolean[array.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        isAllFalse[i] = false;
    }

    return !Arrays.equals(isSelectedChecks, isAllFalse);
}
```

Comment: While this might be a different way to solve the problem, it does not really seem useful, as it's less simple and less efficient than the two top-voted answers.

Answer (score -1):

Kotlin:
if one elemnt is false then not all are selected

```kotlin
return list.filter { isGranted -> isGranted.not() }.isNotEmpty()
```

Answer (score -5):

OK. This is the "most elegant" solution I could come up with on the fly:

```
boolean allTrue = !Arrays.toString(myArray).contains("f");
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: "elegant"? I think not... it may be one line, but instead of checking `n` values of 8 bits each (knowing the size of a `boolean` in an array in memory), it checks a String representation of those, which will be anywhere from `(n * 4) + 2 + ((n-1) * 2)` and `(n * 5) + 2 + ((n-1) * 2)` values of 32 bits each, knowing how `Arrays.toString` methods work and the side of a `char` in memory. (for this particular example, that's 60 to 70 values)

Comment: upvoted for comedy value