# What is the most elegant way to check if all values in a vector<bool> are true?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

This question is similar to this question:
[What is the most elegant way to check if all values in a boolean array are true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260881/what-is-the-most-elegant-way-to-check-if-all-values-in-a-boolean-array-are-true)

But for `vector<bool>` in c++.

How can use `all_of` for this purpose (for example I want to check the value between ranges, element 10 to 20) so I can not use `begin` and `end`.

Comment: Maybe `std::find(cbegin(vector) + 10, cbegin(vector) + 20, false) == cbegin(vector) + 20`.

Comment: You know that functions that take iterators, take any valid iterator, not only `begin()` and `end()`, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `std::all_of`, then just return the value in the predicate function :

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>


int main()
{
    std::vector< bool > v( 30, true );

    const bool all = std::all_of( std::begin(v)+10, std::begin(v)+20, []( const bool v){ return v; } );

    std::cout << all << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: How can I set the range?

Comment: @user1436187 The same way in the other answers.

Comment: what is the different between `std::begin` algorithm and `cbegin`?

Comment: @user1436187 One is a function, the other is a member function.

Comment: Thanks, which of them is faster?

Comment: Is `std::end(v)+20` actually `std::begin(v)+20`?

Answer (score 1):

I'd just try `std::find(begin(v)+10, begin(v)+20, false)` - it returns `begin(v)+20` if all values between 10 and 20 are `true`.