# Checking if all true and reset a Boolean[] array using one-liner lambda expression of Java 8

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Suppose I have a **huge** `Boolean` array `flags`:

```
Boolean[] flags = { true, false, true };    // 3 means "many"
```

I want to do two things on `flags`:

- check whether all the elements are `true` and return an indicator;
- reset all the elements to `false`.

Using lambda expression of Java 8, I can do them as follows:

```
indicator = Arrays.stream(flags).allMatch(flag -> flag);
Arrays.stream(flags).forEach(flag -> flag = false);
return indicator;
```

However this implementation scans `flags` twice. Since `flags` is huge, I don't want this. In addition, I do prefer the lambda way. Is there any way of implementing this `checkIfAllTrueAndReset` semantics with (one-liner) lambda expression which scans `flags` only once?

---

Related but not the same: [What is the most elegant way to check if all values in a boolean array are true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260881/what-is-the-most-elegant-way-to-check-if-all-values-in-a-boolean-array-are-true)

---

***Note:*** I learn a lot from comments and answers. Thank you all!

1. `Stream` is cool, but it is *not* for this.
2. `BitSet` (and its bit-wisely atomic counterpart [`AtomicBitSet`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12425007/1833118)) is more suitable for this (so accepted as the answer; thank others).
3. Side-effects in `map` (`Stream` or generally functional programming) are discouraged.
4. `Arrays.stream(flags).forEach(flag -> flag = false)` (in my code) does *not* set anything!

Comment: Don't. Use a 32-bit integer (int) to do this and perform bitwise operations toggling 0s and 1s.

Comment: Or, use a Bitset. Also note that your forEach loop is a noop. It doesn't modify the values in the array.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter instead of Boolean[]? What about boolean[]? I use Boolean[] (instead of boolean[]) to avoid `Arrays.asList()` in this example. My point is to combine `allMatch` and `forEach`.

Comment: @hengxin [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22753957/4216641) might be related. In short: `Stream`s are not designed to change the underlying datastructure.

Comment: Well, any integer can be used as an array of booleans in a sense. The integer is a series of 1s and 0s (trues and falses). A 32-bit integer then basically contains the same data as a boolean array with a length of 32, with much less overhead. Many large applications (especially games) use this technique because it's much more performant.

You're asking for optimisation, yet you limit yourself to calling streaming functions, which is simply not needed.

Comment: @JBNizet In my real code, I am using `AtomicBoolean[]` for thread-safety. In this post, I have abstracted this out and focus on how to combine `allMatch` and `forEach`. Is `BitSet` thread-safe? Or does it have a thread-safe counterpart? Well, the thread-safety may be another issue. `BitSet` is good for performance.

Comment: No, it's not thread-safe. But if clearing all the bits is supposed to be an atomic operation, using an array of AtomicBooleans is not thread-safe either.

Comment: @JBNizet I only require each (bit) element be accessed atomically (just like the semantics `AtomicBoolean[]` or `AtomicIntegerArray` provides). Then  does `BitSet` have such an alternative?

Comment: AFAIK, no, but you can encapsulate it inside an object and synchronize every access to it. If you really want to stick to an array of AtomicBoolean, then just don't use streams to modify it. That's not what streams are for.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for suggestion. `That's not what streams are for.` This sentence is also helpful (also thank @Turing85).

Comment: `Arrays.stream(flags).forEach(flag -> flag = false)` doesn't set anything.

Comment: @cypressious Great thanks. I have tested it, and you are right. A big mistake in my code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Classic example for using the [`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) class:

> This class implements a vector of bits that grows as needed. Each component of the bit set has a boolean value.

In complexity terms, `BitSet` uses ~1 bit for each `boolean` value, which is way better than using big array of `Boolean` objects.

Regarding checking of all bits are set or not (true or false), the API provides many useful methods - and they're really efficient.

Comment: Thanks. BTW: As mentioned in the comments, I am also interested in thread-safe counterpart to `BitSet`. I googled and found [this](https://code.google.com/p/pitestrunner/source/browse/pitest/src/main/java/org/pitest/boot/AtomicBitSet.java?spec=svncc600208506a965a870ed6dc8a04a81c3c3b1b03&r=cc600208506a965a870ed6dc8a04a81c3c3b1b03).

Answer (score 5):

This is a **bad match for streams and lambdas** and there is no really nice way to do it.

The problem is that steams work with the *elements* of a collection, but you need to modify the actual collection.

I think you are best of using an **old-school for-loop** for this.

---

One not-so-nice solution is to get a stream over the indices of the array and use a `forEach` of that to loop over the array. An `AtomicBoolean` could be used to store if all elements are `true`. This can be run in parallel, but I think an ordinary for-loop is better.

Example:

```
Boolean[] flags = { true, true, true };  

AtomicBoolean allTrue = new AtomicBoolean(true);
IntStream.range(0, flags.length)
    .forEach(ix -> {
        if (!flags[ix]) allTrue.set(false);
        flags[ix] = false;
    });
```

---

#### Solution with atomic boolean

In in the comments of the question it was mentioned that it might be interesting with a solution for `AtomicBoolean`. In that case a solution with streams is possible, since an element can be reset without modifying the original collection.

The solution is really questionably however, so it's probably best to not use it. The problem is that `map` is used both for a side effect (resetting the value) and a mapping operation (extracting the old value). I think it is possible to run it in parallel but it's probably slower than a normal for-loop since the operation on each element is so tiny.

Also note that `allMatch` cannot be used since that operation is short-circuiting and if it finds a `false` it will terminate and subsequent elements will not be reset.

```
AtomicBoolean[] flags = { new AtomicBoolean(true), new AtomicBoolean(false), new AtomicBoolean(true) };  

boolean allTrue = Stream.of(flags)
    .map(b -> b.getAndSet(false))
    .reduce(true, (a, b) -> a && b);
```

Comment: Yes. I learn it today: although `Stream` is cool, it is not for this. Thanks.

Comment: @hengxin: I added a really awkward solution for `AtomicBooleans`.

Comment: It urges me to re-check my existing code that how many times I have modified the original collection in `map`. A big lesson.

Comment: You should use `AtomicBoolean`'s `getAndSet(false)` method within the `map` operation.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner: Of course! That is much better, thanks!

Comment: @hengxin: *"how many times I have modified the original collection in map"* It is not that it is absolutely forbidden, but it goes against the functional idea of the stream library. The [documentation of `map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) says that the operation should be *[non-interfering*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#NonInterference) and [*stateless*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness).

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to do this with streams in one line, then you can do something like this

```
boolean allTrue = IntStream.range(0, flags.length).reduce(0,
    (result, i) -> flags[i] ^ (flags[i] = false) ? result : 1) == 0;
```

However this does not look like a good idea, and I would lean towards using a `BitSet` as suggested by @MarounMaroun

Answer (score 0):

If you know the size of the array in advance, you can check in *O(1)* time if all the flags are true. Store the size of the array in a variable `arraySize` and set an additional variable `indexCount` to `0`. Instead of changing the flags within the array to `true`/`false`, increment/decrement the `indexCount` variable. If you want to know whether all flags are true, simply check `arraySize == indexCount`. If you do not need to know the current flag of specific items, you can completely dispense with the array.

This is also applicable, if you have to check whether a specific amount of flags is true.